# Adding street View in Google Maps -Android and iPhone

Tags: google-maps, dataset, openstreetmap, google-street-view

I'm trying to develop an application that show the traffic congestion in country like Saudi Arabia , I did some research and found that Street View is not available for Saudi Arabia. If this is true, how can I implement or add street view to google maps in order to use it
I have a street view from a shape file .. and I want it to be embedded with Google Maps. Is this possible?

What are the other solutions if the answer is no? can I use OpenStreetMap with google Maps?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Google maps with openstreetmaps http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/downloads/detail?name=osmdroid-google-3.0.4.jar&can=2&q=